# Unable to detect custom object using tensorflow object detection (despite training loss < 1.0)

Tags: tensorflow, object-detection

Unable to detect custom object after training using tensorflow object detection. There are No bounding boxes drawn at all. The image is exactly same as input. Even for the training example image its not able to recognize anything

I am trying to detect a specific object like car by doing following

1. 190 training samples
2. 40 test samples
3. Number of classes is 1

My training loss  begins around 14.0 and ends with 0.7 after 1000 iterations. I am using `ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco` and only additionally changing the config file, as follows as my images are all "around" this size, apart from running for 1000 iterations.

```
image_resizer {
      fixed_shape_resizer {
        height: 450
        width: 300
      }
    }
```

Please help how to debug this. I dont know where exactly to start.
I have annotated (drawn bounding box) images twice without any help. The images are of sizes varying from `425x300` to `450x300`.

Comment: I just realized my .pbtxt file has different casing compared to the .tfrecord which was generated using the .csv file. I am re-running the training now, will update if it helps. If there are any other thoughts meanwhile please share

Comment: One thought: try training on a single sample and testing on the same sample. If it can learn that, then it may just be a matter of training more (lower learning rate, increase number of epochs, etc.), but if it can't learn a single sample then your problem may be more systemic.

Comment: Thank you Engineero. It indeed turned out to be casing difference between class name in .pbtxt and the .csv. I have initial decent result to play with further